# ¿Por que no se ve una imagen en html?

Tags: html

Esto es lo que me sucede.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`<h1><img src= "Bibliotecas/Imágenes/logo.gif" width="100" height="100">Trabajadores Vigentes</h1>`

Comment: Puede ser que la imagen no se encuentra en el folder especificado,  e recomiendo dar clic derecho en la imagen, inspeccionar el código y ver donde se esta buscando la imagen

Comment: `Vigentes.php/vigentes.php` parece que es un _fallo_ con .htaccess y como la ruta de la imagen es relativa en lugar de absoluta (o relativa a la raíz), entonces la imagen se romperá porque la ruts no es correcta.

Comment: Me parece que puede ser el acento en la ruta de tu "src" prueba quitando el acento de tu carpeta y de tu atributo y vuelve a intentarlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomendaría que en lo posible no utilices **mayúsculas** en tus rutas a archivos y tampoco **acentos**. Si es posible cambia tu ruta a:

```
src= bibliotecas/imagenes/logo.gif
```

Esto lo logras cambiando el nombre de la carpeta **"Bibliotecas"** a **"bibliotecas"** y la carpeta  **"Imágenes"** por **"imagenes"**

Por qué es necesario esto?

Porque te será más sencillo (dado el caso) migrar de un sistema operativo a otro ya que linux por ejemplo es **sensible** al uso de mayúsculas y los acentos constituyen una parte de los llamados **caracteres especiales** cuyo trato no es igual a caracteres como "1" o "A" o "b" por ejemplo.

Además aparte de solucionar tu problema dejas mejor estandarizado tu sistema para que el día de mañana si se requiere implementar un **framework** la adaptación del sistema sea mucho más sencilla. Por ejemplo el **framework** de **PHP** llamado **Codeigniter** utiliza las rutas como nombre de **clases** y **métodos** (que son sensibles a uso de mayúsculas) lo cual te podría traer problemas si requieres adaptar tu sistema a este **framework** de trabajo

**Observación:** Noto que la ruta de tu archivo presente en el navegador de la imagen adjuntada (localhost:8080/...) posees dos archivos con terminación **.php** estás seguro que debe ser así? incluso por el nombre de ambos parece que intentaste repetirlo (uno se llama vigete.php y el otro vigente.php) sería bueno que chequees también esa ruta porque parece no estar bien implementada.

Me he fijado en que el usuario **@AlvaroMontoro** te ha comentado lo relacionado a la ruta **vigente.php**, por favor revisa su comentario realizado en tu pregunta. Es tal como dice el Sr. Alvaro la ruta es incorrecta y lo más probable es que tengas un problema con la forma en que utilizas el **mod_rewrite** de **Apache**

Espero te sea de ayuda. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias posibilidades de por que no se puede ver una imagen:

- La ruta/nombre de archivo esta mal escrito
- El servidor donde esta alojada la imagen no esta disponible
- Estas detrás algun firewall o algo que evita que puedas acceder a donde
  esta alojada la imagen

en el caso de tu ejemplo pones que la ruta de la imagen es:

Bibliotecas/Imágenes/logo.gif

sin embargo si la imagen esta en una subcarpeta prueba:

```
<h1><img src= "/Bibliotecas/Imágenes/logo.gif" width="100" height="100">Trabajadores Vigentes</h1>
```

además veo que tu nombre de carpeta tiene una tilde, trata de no usar carácteres especiales como letras tildadas en nombres de carpetas eso solo te va a traer problemas

Answer (score 0):

Antes que todo, checa la extensión y nombre real, no sobre windows, en una ventana cmd, verifica que el nombre sea por ejemplo:

```
`miImagen.jpg`
```

Muchas ocasiones al bajar una imagen en windows la renombramos y quedan así

```
`miImagen.jpg.jpg`
```

Abre cmd y verifica que el nombre sea el correcto

Comment: Te recomiendo que si conoces la linea de comando especifica la pongas, tambien la fuente, puedes leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)